# How to set the Teamcity sonarqube plugin module list externally?

Tags: maven, sonarqube, teamcity, multi-module

We are using Teamcity in conjunction with the SonarQube plugin for some maven multi-module projects.

As we are potentially adding modules to one or the other project, I would like to set the "Modules" parameter of the SonarQube plugin programmatically or via some environment variable instead of having to manually edit it in the plugin's config.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

For my TeamCity setup I have a global variable for my SonarQube exclusions. I can change all exclusions or override for specific projects. If you want to set this programatically, you could use the TeamCity API to update a similar variable either on the project or global level.

If you need a starting point, I have a script that updates build numbers I can share.